# read 11 sku number only (ean 13 code) in textbox

Tags: php, html

I have barcode scanner and reads ean13 but it only displays 11 sku number in textbox. I have also tried in notepad++ and still display 11 numbers supposed to be 12. Let's say for ex : 0000000127158 sku number , displays 00000012715 in textbox , it should be 000000012715.

Comment: So what does the barcode scanner output if you let it output to say excel or wordpad?

Comment: i have already edited my answer. it's working on visual studio , foxpro vb textboxes . it displays 12 code.

Comment: Is the scanner configured to strip the checksum digit?

Comment: no , but why it normally works on the others without checksum?